# Why `linedelimiter` does not work for bag.read_text?

Tags: dask

I am trying to load yaml from files created by

```
entries = bag.from_sequence([{1:2}, {3:4}])
yamls = entries.map(yaml.dump)
yamls.to_textfiles(r'\*.yaml.gz')
```

with

```
yamls = bag.read_test(r'\*.yaml.gz', linedelimiter='\n\n)
```

but it reads files line by line. How to read yamls from files?

UPDATE:

1. While `blocksize=None` `read_text` reads files line by line.
2. If `blocksize` is set, you could read compressed files.

How to overcome this? Is uncompressing the files is the only option?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `linedelimiter` is used not for the sense you have in mind, but *only* for separating the larger blocks. As you say, when you compress with gzip, the file is no longer random-accessible, and blocks cannot be used at all.

It would be possible to pass the `linedelimiter` into the functions that turn chunks of data into lines (in `dask.bag.text`, if you are interested).

For now, a workaround could look like this:

```
yamls = bag.read_test(r'\*.yaml.gz').map_partitions(
    lambda x: '\n'.join(x).split(delimiter))
```