# Dask getting "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" in the middle of a file

Tags: python, dask

I'm making a bag from a plain txt file - it's got a bunch of reviews, delimited by two newlines.  But, sometimes - and I really can't predict when - it gives me  `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/c/Workspaces/Books/Dask/foods.txt'` while processing it

Here's the actual code

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
import numpy as np
import dask.bag as bag
import os

def get_next_part(file, start_index, span_index=0, blocksize=1000):
    file.seek(start_index)
    buffer = file.read(blocksize + span_index).decode('cp1252')
    delimiter_position = buffer.find('\n\n')
    if delimiter_position == -1:
        return get_next_part(file, start_index, span_index + blocksize)
    else:
        file.seek(start_index)
        return start_index, delimiter_position

def get_item(filename, start_index, delimiter_position, encoding='cp1252'):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file_handle:
        file_handle.seek(start_index)
        text = file_handle.read(delimiter_position).decode(encoding)
        return dict((element.split(': ')[0], element.split(': ')[1])
                               if len(element.split(': ')) > 1
                               else ('unknown', element)
                               for element in text.strip().split('\n'))    


with open(f"{os.getcwd()}/foods.txt", 'rb') as file_handle:
    size = file_handle.seek(0,2) - 1
    more_data = True
    output = []
    current_position = next_position = 0
    while more_data:
        if current_position >= size:
            more_data = False
        else:
            current_position, next_position = get_next_part(file_handle, current_position, 0)
            output.append((current_position, next_position))
            current_position = current_position + next_position + 2

with ProgressBar():
    reviews = (bag.from_sequence(output, npartitions=104)
               .map(lambda x: get_item(f"{os.getcwd()}/foods.txt", 
                                       x[0], 
                                       x[1]))
              .compute())
```

Sometimes it works fine, but other times it gives me something along these lines (different percentage every time):

```
[##########                              ] | 26% Completed | 54.3s
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-90a316620d10> in <module>()
     42 with ProgressBar():
     43     reviews = (bag.from_sequence(output, npartitions=104)
---> 44                .map(lambda x: get_item(f"{os.getcwd()}/foods.txt", 
     45                                        x[0],
     46                                        x[1]))

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    154         dask.base.compute
    155         """
--> 156         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    157         return result
    158 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    396     keys = [x.__dask_keys__() for x in collections]
    397     postcomputes = [x.__dask_postcompute__() for x in collections]
--> 398     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    399     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    400 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/multiprocessing.py in get(dsk, keys, num_workers, func_loads, func_dumps, optimize_graph, pool, **kwargs)
    190                            get_id=_process_get_id, dumps=dumps, loads=loads,
    191                            pack_exception=pack_exception,
--> 192                            raise_exception=reraise, **kwargs)
    193     finally:
    194         if cleanup:

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    460                         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    461                     else:
--> 462                         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    463                 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    464                 state['cache'][key] = res

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py in reraise(exc, tb)
    109     def reraise(exc, tb=None):
    110         if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 111             raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    112         raise exc
    113 

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py in execute_task()
    228     try:
    229         task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 230         result = _execute_task(task, data)
    231         id = get_id()
    232         result = dumps((result, id))

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py in _execute_task()
    117         func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    118         args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
--> 119         return func(*args2)
    120     elif not ishashable(arg):
    121         return arg

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/bag/core.py in reify()
   1589 def reify(seq):
   1590     if isinstance(seq, Iterator):
-> 1591         seq = list(seq)
   1592     if seq and isinstance(seq[0], Iterator):
   1593         seq = list(map(list, seq))

~/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/bag/core.py in map_chunk()
   1749     else:
   1750         for a in zip(*args):
-> 1751             yield f(*a)
   1752 
   1753     # Check that all iterators are fully exhausted

<ipython-input-1-90a316620d10> in <lambda>()
     44                .map(lambda x: get_item(f"{os.getcwd()}/foods.txt", 
     45                                        x[0],
---> 46                                        x[1]))
     47               .compute())

<ipython-input-1-90a316620d10> in get_item()
     18 
     19 def get_item(filename, start_index, delimiter_position, encoding='cp1252'):
---> 20     with open(filename, 'rb') as file_handle:
     21         file_handle.seek(start_index)
     22         text = file_handle.read(delimiter_position).decode(encoding)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/c/Workspaces/Books/Dask/foods.txt'
```

I've tried messing with the partition numbers - leaving it as default (101), or making sure it's a multiple of 4.  Doesn't seem to have an effect.

Anyone know what's going on here?  It usually works if I run it a second time, but that's still tough to deal with.

I'm using the latest version of Dask.  Using conda, it's all in Jupyterlab, and I'm running it from Windows Subsystem for Linux

Thanks!

Comment: is '/mnt/c/Workspaces/Books/Dask/foods.txt' exits? are you creating it in some other code?

Comment: It definitely exists.

Comment: try `file_handle.close()` once you are done reading from the file. In your code, there are 2 places where you are opening it as file_handle. so in both cases, once you are done with reading from the file, do `file_handle.close()`.

Comment: I'm using the `with open` context manager, though.  Or did I forget to put it somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Comment: but you are not closing it.

Comment: My understanding was that when you use the Context Manager, you don't close it manually.

Comment: Did you give it a try to close it manually and running it?

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to fix my initial read method, but was able to find another way of doing the parallel read (with native Dask objects too!)

Sections were delimited with `\n\n` and the `linedelimiter` argument to `bag` didn't mean what I thought it meant, but with this I was able to figure a way to get the sections I needed: [Why `linedelimiter` does not work for bag.read_text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320789/why-linedelimiter-does-not-work-for-bag-read-text)

```
        bag.read_text(
            f"{os.getcwd()}/foods.txt",
            encoding="cp1252",
            blocksize="10MB",
            linedelimiter="\n\n",
        )
        .map_partitions(lambda x: "".join(x).split("\n\n"))
```